# Visualising current in the LCR circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, capacitance, inductance

I just went through the theory of the serial LCR circuit.

There current and voltage are 90 degrees out of phase with each other. Now I was trying to imagine an animation with just dots. And I visualized it in my head like a longitudinal sound wave. So, having alternate zones where density of dots is squeezed and stretched.

But in a longitudinal sound wave pressure and the pass-through rate are in the phase.

- How would 90 deg phase difference between pressure & current look like in LCR circuit's AC if visualized as oscillating dots?
- Will it be longitudinal wave?

Comment: What would the dots represent? The electrons? In your animation, what would be the x axis?

Comment: Lets say that dots are positive holes, as per convention and axis is just along the center of the conductor. I am just interested in the visualisation of the phase difference between the voltage and current. But not the phasor animation, because that's well known.

Comment: @COROVCID I'm not sure I'm matching what you want, but I think that if you draw two sine waves shifted 90 degrees, and "fill" them with dots between zero and the limit of the waves, does the trick.

Comment: @cinico where are dots going to have the highest density? Bellow the peak of the current or peak of the voltage?

Comment: There will not be a variation of density of the charge carriers. Instead, I think you should imagine an homogeneous group of carriers going back and forth (current) but phased 90 degrees (a quarter period) with the applied "pressure" (voltage).

Comment: @cinico Something like that. I tried again to visualize it and I came up with this: two distinct regions with high and low density of charges, but the low density front moving forward at very high speed and acceleration. So density is low, but speed is very high. High speed means higher current. Its hard to visualize, but I guess that's the closest to real thing.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

Screen capture:
[image: LRC Circuit]
http://www.falstad.com/circuit/

The default circuit, as shown, is an LRC circuit.

On the Schematic:
Gray is 0V
Green is Positive Voltage
Red is Negative Voltage
The yellow dots are a visualization of current: positive holes.

The graphs along the bottom, from left to right, are for the Inductor, Capacitor, and Resistor.
The Green waveform is the voltage across the component.
The Yellow waveform is the current through the component.

---

So to answer your questions:

- In the animation above, the 90 deg phase difference is shown since the yellow dots' velocity (current) is maximum when the voltage across the inductor is 0V (gray on both sides). The dots' velocity is 0 when there exists the maximum absolute voltage (red or green).
- Current shouldn't be represented as longitudinal waves, since the current through a series circuit must be all equal. (It could possibly be represented with longitudinal waves in the context of electron charge on a capacitor, but electrical engineers still represent this as current flow, called displacement current.)

Comment: very nice! @COROVICD Notice how the yellow dots (charge) do not move when the voltage is maximum (or minimum), and have maximum velocity (current) when the voltage is zero. This shows how the current and voltage are phased 90 degrees