# In mechanical systems, it is easier to understand concept of natural frequency, could somebody explain natural frequency in electronic elements?

Tags: classical-mechanics, frequency, oscillators, resonance, electronics

In mechanical systems, natural frequency simply means the frequency at which the body will oscillate when it is disturbed(assuming the body will suffer zero resistance in motion) but wihle studying electronics it has become harder to visualise this thing.

Answer (score 0):

The same holds for an electronic system. The current keeps oscillating back and forth after the system has been disturbed. [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/216210/visualising-current-in-the-lcr-circuit/217578#217578) contains a nice visualization of what happens in an LRC circuit.